# Can't login with FBchat 1.9.7 python (failed)

Tags: python, api, facebook

Hi :) I use: https://fbchat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

I wanted to try make simple msg bot, but when I tried to login I have this error:

```
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kryzdeg/projects/nie_zesraj_sie_fbmsg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 205, in login
    self._state = State.login(
  File "/home/kryzdeg/projects/nie_zesraj_sie_fbmsg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 151, in login
    return cls.from_session(session=session)
  File "/home/kryzdeg/projects/nie_zesraj_sie_fbmsg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 190, in from_session
    revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's my code:

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *

email = input("Email: ")
password = input("Password: ")

print(email, password)

client = Client(email, password)

print(client.uid)

client.logout()
```

Email and password are correct and I don't use 2FA.

Comment: Looks like the python fbchat package is broken.